# python - web scraping BeautifulSoup and urllib

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am using python 3.4 and my script looks like:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.embassy-worldwide.com/"

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
#req = Request(url, headers)

try:
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers)
    #print (req)
except HTTPError as e:
    print('Error code: ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
    print('Reason: ', e.reason)
else:
    print('good!')

print (req)

#html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    html = response.read()
print(html)
```

the code above results in an error:

**ValueError: Content-Length should be specified for iterable data of type  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}**

How can I get the html code and then iterate the tags to get a list with all countries?

Comment: Please, please, please use `urllib3`.

Comment: what's so bad with urllib? can you give an example as a solution?

Comment: `urllib` has many known flaws which are fixed in `urllib2` and `urllib3` (and `requests`, which is based on `urllib3`). `urllib` can randomly fail (especially on high payload with pooling) without any good indications. Furthermore with this library, in the community, it's common sense to use the latest version to prevent old recurring issues you might automatically solve with the newer.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info. Switched to urllib3, but still fighting how to get the HTML content and pass it to BeautifulSoup.

Comment: `req = requests.get(url, headers)` and `soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this style in urllib3:

```
import sys
import re
import time
import pprint
import codecs
import unicodedata
import urllib3
import json

urllib3.disable_warnings()

cookie = '_session_id=29913b5f1b8836d2a8387ef4db00745e'
header = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17'
url = 'https://yoururl.com/'
m = urllib3.PoolManager(num_pools = 15)

r = m.request('GET', url, None, {'User-Agent' : header, 'Cookie' : cookie})

print(r.data)
```

The imports are more than needed. It's just a snippet from a bigger part of a scraper I use. And mine uses some regex because the tiny snippets I need are in my case faster in regex than a full beautifulsoup implementation.

Comment: Thanks, by using the url: *http://www.embassy-worldwide.com*, how would you het the HTML from that page, so I could use it to scrape the page?

Comment: `r.data` contains the raw dump of the HTTP Response body.

Comment: Simplified the code a little for one request. Remove the cookie entry if it's not needed.